# chef not loading nginx

Tags: nginx, chef-infra, vagrant

I am using vagrant and chef. I have a recipe that should load and configure nginx.

In my vagrantfile I have:

```
  chef.cookbooks_path = [ 'chef/cookbooks', 'chef/cookbooks-sources' ]
```

In my chefFile:

```
cookbook 'nginx',
  git: 'https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/nginx.git'
```

In my recipe metadata.rb (in cookbooks-sources):

```
depends "nginx"
```

In my recipe I have:

```
 include_recipe 'nginx'
```

Cheffile.lock looks like:

```
DEPENDENCIES
  apt (>= 0)
  cassandra (>= 0)
  curl (>= 0)
  elasticsearch (>= 0)
  java (>= 0)
  java_extras (>= 0)
  phantomjs (>= 0)
  postgresql (>= 0)
  python (>= 0)
  redis (>= 0)
  rvm (>= 0)
  sbt-extras (>= 0)
  windows (= 1.8.6)
```

when I run vagrant up or provision I get the following:

```
[2013-07-02T20:21:40+00:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::CookbookNotFound: Cookbook nginx not found. If you're loading nginx from another cookbook, make sure you configure the dependency in your metadata
```

How do I fix my error?

Answer (score 1):

Your *Cheffile.lock* does not list the nginx dependency but many others, so there is something missing here...

Did you run `librarian-chef install` (or `update`) after adding the nginx cookbook? You should have directory *chef/cookbooks/nginx/*.

Librarian-Chef also installs by default to *./cookbooks/*, so with your setup you need to give it `--path="chef/cookbooks"` at the first time (assuming Cheffile is at the same directory than Vagrantfile).

Comment: +1 There is also a useful librarian plugin for vagrant that will automatically run an install/update.

Answer (score -1):

Are you using a cookbook manager such as Berkshelf? If not, you should look into that, it can assist you with this problem. (I'm not familiar with chefFile, perhaps this is a cookbook manager).

A (not so ideal) option to solve this would be to manually clone the nginx cookbook repo and put it in `chef/cookbooks` or `chef/cookbooks-sources` and this would solve your problem.

Comment: Cheffile is used by librarian-chef, an alternative tool to berkshelf.